# How to perform road network analysis in R by defining topology rules

Tags: r, gis, r-sf

I have a road network as an sf layer in R. I would like to check and correct its topology so that all dangles are removed, undershoots are extended, and all intersections happen at a vertex. Only genuine dead-ends (cul-de-sacs) will be maintained and they have been defined as the road segment that ends at a distance more than 500m from a vertex.
By googling around, I am only seeing codes like this:

```
roads %<>% st_make_valid(geos_method = "valid_structure", geos_keep_collapsed = F)
```

In this code, I don't have an option to define these rules I want to enforce.
Are there other packages that can better serve my purpose? How?

Comment: What you describe might be a case for {sfnetworks} package - have a look at the https://luukvdmeer.github.io/sfnetworks/articles/sfn02_preprocess_clean.html - vignette.

Comment: You need to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) of your data.